# How to exclude leading hyphens from justification in dialogue lines using CSS + HTML?

Tags: css, dialog, justify

I am writing fiction story in my blog, and the text is horizontally justified (as in printed books). However, this makes a negative impact on dialogue lines, because the distance between the leading hyphen and the following word gets justified as well. Eventually, for different lines of dialogue the first word is not aligned. Is it possible to overcome the issue using some CSS + HTML trick? Is it possible to achieve similar in Google Docs or Libre Office Writer? Thanks.

Sample screenshot (please ignore the actual wording - this is just to illustrate the case). As you can see, the first word ('Good' in both cases) is not left-aligned (I don't care about the rest of words).

[image: Sample text]

In fact, I'd like to treat leading hyphen, followed by a single space and one word, as a single word. I tried to do something like:

```
dstart::before { content: "\2014\00a0"; }</style><br/>
<span class="dstart">Good</span>
```

But my browser (Firefox) still recognized space character and performed similar alignment. I assume, there is no need to check in the other major browsers if one of those does not accept my approach.

The following solves the issue:

```
<span style="padding-right: 0.5em;">-</span>Good...
```

However, when doing copy/paste there will be no space between hyphen and 'Good' in plan text, and therefore, still **not acceptable** for me.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to the result you have.

Comment: If you are composing your story in HTML CSS page ,yes . But its case dependent and you need to elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve with some page or screenshot .

Comment: @shadeed9 Sorry for being unclear. Please see the screenshot I've added

Comment: Rounin's suggestion (OPTION 2) is really interesting. I decided to mark his answer as solution, although I am unable to use for my case. The reason is simple: I am using WordPress.com Premium (not .org), and therefore, I can only change CSS or pure HTML (any attempt to embed script gets blocked). This solution might still be very useful to the other people who use, for instance, Blogger

Comment: Sorry, in fact, this solution only adds leading dashes, but does not solve the original problem of justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found solution myself. Sorry Rounin and Oriol for taking so much of your time and thanks a lot for your genuine effort to help me. As I mentioned, I needed leading hyphen, space and the first word to be treated as a single word. Therefore, no need for any styling or special lists, but simply to use **–&ensp;** or similar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

 <style>
     p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: justify; }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <p>–&ensp;Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick-George-Harry-Ian-Jake-Keith-Lachlan.</p>
 <p>–&ensp;Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick, George-Harry-Ian-Jake-Keith-Lachlan-Mark.</p>
 <p>–&ensp;Good morning, Mr. Pickwick.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case text on page gets displayed as expected, and copy/paste also works as expected. I am using paragraph wrapper **<p>**, because in **WordPress** it gets injected implicitly when I write something like this:

–&ensp;Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick-George-Harry-

–&ensp;Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick, George-Harry-Ian-Jake-Keith-Lachlan-Mark.

–&ensp;Good morning, Mr. Pickwick.

And when I copy/paste plain text from my page displayed, each block is separated with blank line. Yes, I want it to be that way, because for plain text it would be easier for reading.

Comment: Good idea. Note the default is `text-justify: auto`, which is implementation dependent, so some UA might still add extra space. `text-justify: inter-word` would be safer because it adjusts spacing only at word separators, which don't include fixed-width spaces like `&ensp;`. There is small browser support for that property, though.

Comment: That's a great approach. Now I've seen your own solution, I've a clearer idea of what you were aiming for all along. I know you aren't able to add scripts to your WP setup, but, given that HTML is poorly equipped to mark up literary dialogue, a combination of your solution and a modified version of the `.js` script I posted below (where `'&#8212; &nbsp; &nbsp;'` is swapped for `'<span>&#8212;&ensp;</span>'`) might be the start of an approach toward marking up literary dialogue that really looks like literary dialogue, which doesn't require manually inserted _em dashes_ before every utterance.

Comment: Thank you Oriol and Rounin for your kind words. Thanks a lot Oriol for drawing attention to text-justify - I never used that (although saw it when was looking for CSS for justification). I'll check inter-word option and, possibly, include that. Regarding Rounin's suggestion - yes, it looks interesting if JS is allowed, but please keep also in mind that it is better to keep text as close to plain text as possible, because at the end of the day it is a text, which is not only displayed, but edited too :) Therefore, I wanted to avoid HTML markup as much as I could.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to share the link to the actual text. It's a pretty funny sci-fi story, but in Russian. Hope someday to translate that. However, in that case, I am afraid, it will transform from literary to illiterary.

Answer (score 1):

You can float it to make it out-of-flow:

```css
.quote::before {
  content: "\2014\00a0";
  float: left;
}
```

```css
.quote::before {
  content: "\2014\00a0";
  float: left;
}
.quote { text-align: justify; }
.quote::after { content: ""; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="quote">Good morning Alex-Ben-Charlie</div>
```

However, the dash seems part of content, and therefore it might be better to include it in a real element instead of a pseudo one.

```css
.dash {
  float: left;
}
.quote { text-align: justify; }
.quote::after { content: ""; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <span class="dash">—&nbsp;</span>Good morning Alex-Ben-Charlie
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oriol for your detailed suggestion. Unfortunately, this has a very undesirable effect of stretching **any** line of text regardless of how many words are there. Whereas plain justification will stretch a line of text conditionally - my rough estimate is that the line of text should be at least more than a half page width.

And when I remove **content: "";** the whole thing acts like plain justification.

Sorry, I am afraid, I am putting too hard restrictions.

Comment: @AlexanderIurovetski Not sure what you are talking about. Justification always justifies, independently on the number of words. My answer doesn't alter this behavior, it only prevents space between the dash and the first word.

Comment: Please try this:

**<style> div { float-left; text-align: justify; } </style>
<div>- Good morning, Mr. Pickwick.</div>**.

If window is wide enough nothing will be stretched to full window width. But when you reduce window width, then at some point the text will stretch. If you can't reproduce, just reduce content to the first 2 words.

And in your example the strecth works regardless (until you remove **content: "";** but in that case we get to the initial issue with justification).

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to mark up your conversations using an unordered list *[1]*, where each list item has an *em dash* as a custom bullet.

See this example:

```css
ul {
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
}

li {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li::before {
content: '\2014 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0';
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick-George-Harry-Ian-Jake-Keith-Lachlan.</li>
<li>Good morning, Mr. Pickwick.</li>
</ul>
```

[1] *I understand that `<ul>` and `<li>` are not the most obvious items with which to mark up a literary conversation, but since the HTML5 `<dialog>` element has been repurposed from its originally intended usage (see: http://html5doctor.com/a-little-more-conversation-with-dialog/) and is now in an experimental state (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog), there is, currently, no specific element for marking up conversations.*

## ======

**Option 2**

An alternative solution, *if you need to keep hyphens in plain text when doing copy/paste* might be the following example, in which a script automatically inserts an *em dash* at the start of each `<li>`, after the page has loaded:

```js
var dialogue = document.getElementsByClassName('dialogue')[0];
var exchanges = dialogue.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < exchanges.length; i++) {
exchanges[i].innerHTML = '&#8212; &nbsp; &nbsp;' + exchanges[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
ul {
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dialogue">
<li>Good morning, Alex-Ben-Charlie-David-Eugene-Frederick-George-Harry-Ian-Jake-Keith-Lachlan.</li>
<li>Good morning, Mr. Pickwick.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rounin for providing such comprehensive example. In fact, I considered unordered lists as well. Unfortunately, I had to reject this approach, because it is very important to me to keep hyphens in plain text when doing copy/paste. This was also the reason I rejected my other approach, which kept hyphens and used padding for spacing.

I am afraid, I am putting too hard restrictions. At the moment, spacing between leading hyphen and the first word is the minor issue comparing to side effects any solution causes.

Comment: If we take into account the following -  _it is very important to me to keep hyphens in plain text when doing copy/paste_ - this rules out using `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements which are part of the document's presentation (ie. not part of the document's content). Instead, you can automatically insert real content into the document, using a script after the rest of the `html` document has loaded. I have posted a demonstration of this above. (See: Option 2).

Comment: OPTION 2 is really interesting, and I decided to mark your answer as solution, although I am unable to use for my case. The reason is simple: I am using WordPress.com Premium (not .org), and therefore, I can only change CSS or pure HTML (any attempt to embed script gets blocked). This solution might still be very useful to the other people who use, for instance, Blogger

Comment: Using `li` may be a good idea. But this doesn't prevent the extra space between the dash and the first word. In fact I don't see how this addresses the problem. The acceptance puzzles me.

Comment: Sorry Rounin, I must agree with Oriol. When I tried your option 2 myself in full, it **didn't really work**. Yes, it adds leading dashes as symbols, but it doesn't solve initial problem: if I define **text-align:justify;** for **ul**, then I get to point 1 - the spacing between dash and first word is variable again (see my original screenshot). Sorry, I have to remove solution mark from your suggestion.